# Incoming Post Request with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, http, express, post

I am trying to take a POST request that I will receive with information to input into my fields. I want to receive it, input into my fields, and submit again to my system. Is there an easier way or how should i do this? I am using Node.js with Express currently.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "submit again to my system"?

Comment: Please post a snippet of what you have this far. It's difficult to see what you're asking for.